# databricks-spark no jobs, tasks, or stages are being shown

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm using Databricks 3.5, Apache Spark 2.2.1.

I'm running a cell in a databricks notebook with the code below.

```
(df
 .write
 .partitionBy("date", "user_id")
 .mode("overwrite")
 .parquet(write_path)
)
```

I pressed shift+enter in the cell and the progress bar runs.  However, I don't see any jobs, stages, or tasks at all.  I've let cell run for a few hours and I still don't see anything running yet.

The dataframe 'df' has ~12 million rows.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Community Edition or standard? How many workers did you configure for your cluster?

Comment: @silvio 

I'm using the standard edition.

I tried both 8 and 20 workers and no jobs, stages, or workers were were shown.